# Problemas com APK react-native

Tags: react, react-native

Quando eu compilo o projeto ele gera o `APK` na pasta `C:\Users<usuario>\Desktop\projetos\appTeste\android\app\build\outputs\apk`.
Se eu pegar o `APK` e colocar em um celular ele instala certinho, porém se eu alterar alguma coisa no código, recompilar e gerar o novo `APK`, por mais que eu exclua o anterior e pegue o novo gerado, ao instalar no celular ele instala a versão antiga do código.

> *Por exemplo:* 
>   Tenho um texto escrito `"Olá"`.
>  
>   Se eu pegar o APK e instalar no celular, ele instala e mostra o texto `"Olá"`. 
>   Se eu alterar o texto para `"Olá nova versão"` recompilar e pegar o novo `APK` gerado, ele instala no celular mas ainda mostra apenas o texto `"Olá"`, que seria da versão anterior do projeto.

Se eu usar um `APK` Assinado, feito o build direto pelo `Android Studio` também da o mesmo problema.

Comment: Amigo estou com o mesmo problema, você conseguiu solucionar?

Answer (score -4):

Tenta "resetar" a build anterior e gere novamente, e alterar a versão do código também, assim como o brother acima disse